# What might cause Edge DevTools to show empty Source contents for some source-mapped files, and not others?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, svelte, edge-devtools

I suddenly began having a problem with Edge DevTools this morning not displaying source (source tab is empty) for some source-mapped files, but showing it fine for others.

**Good:**

[image: Good]

**Bad:**

[image: Bad]

Any ideas what might cause this? I tried disabling source maps, then reenabling. I tried shutting Edge down completely, then restarting, nothing is working. Chrome DevTools works just fine.

My project is using `Svelte` which uses `rollup`. I can see the browser get the `bundle.js.map` file and it does show my original files under `src`, so it's getting the map.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what the issue was?

Comment: No, it's still unsolved and still happening. I've stopped using Edge altogether when developing because it simply doesn't work. Chrome does.

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome in a project, but I have just tried with another project, and in there the sources are also empty (I remember this used to work before when I first tried that project, some time ago)...

Comment: Really weird. I was able to use Opera to debug that... svelte sources were shown fine in there. But, as of today, after an Opera update, the svelte sources are also gone from Opera! So, now in all 3: edge, chrome and opera, I don't see the sources anymore, all of a sudden!
I assume it is some Chromium related bug, since all 3 browsers are now affected by this.